# Prettier not formatting single quotes in HTML file

Tags: html, prettier, single-quotes

I have my prettierrc.json file set up for Prettier to change my double quotes into single quotes. It works fine with my script.js file, but is not working with my index.html file.

Prettier will format all other parts of the index.html file (it will correct tabs, delete unnecessary spaces, etc), but it will only change quotes to double quotes.

Here are the contents of my prettierrc.json file:

{
"singleQuote": true
}

To format the code in my script.js files, I simply type the following command into the terminal, and the double quotes are automatically formatted into single quotes:

npx prettier --write script.js

But when I type the following command to format my index.html file, it formats all quotes as double quotes:

npx prettier --write index.html

Prettier was originally installed globally and as a VSCode extension, but when the HTML document was not able to be formatted, I uninstalled Prettier globally, uninstalled the VSCode Prettier extension, and made sure that all VSCode settings were back to normal, and there are no remnants of Prettier in any node module folders or anywhere else. I also uninstalled eslint and deleted the eslint-prettier config files for good measure.

Once everything was nice and fresh as if installing prettier for the first time, I installed Prettier locally in a brand new project folder, and created test index.html and script.js files just to get Prettier working.

Here are the things I've tried so far:
-Uninstalling and reinstalling prettier multiple times
-Installing the VSCode Prettier extension and selecting "single quotes" in the settings
-writing code in the package.json file to set singleQuote as true
-creating an editor.config file and adding code to set singleQuote as true
-Uninstalling eslint from the computer and double checking that it is not located in any .json or node module files

None of this seems to be working, any ideas?

Comment: It appears to me that Prettier is aware of this bug, and they will have the issue fix soon. In the meantime,  I found an easy, temporary fix for this issue while we are waiting for the commits to be approved with prettier.

Turn off format on save, install the VSCode extension "Replace Quotes", and create a keyboard shortcut for the Replace Single command.

Then make a keyboard shortcut to run Prettier.

Then the work flow will go like this for HTML docs:

Write code, keyboard shortcut for Prettier, keyboard shortcut for Replace Single, Save.

Comment: For reference, here an explanation why JSX ignores `singleQuote: true`: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/656

Comment: For JSX there is `--jsx-single-quote` [Github Merge Request](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/4798#issuecomment-434052339), [Prettier Docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/next/options#jsx-quotes)